# SQL Select id and output of exists in single SQL query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables with primary key(A.Id), foreign key(EquipmentKey) reference between 2 tables A and B. Now I want result like A.Id, Whether it exists in B or not.

This is the query I am trying. Can it be achieved easily in single query?
Below query doesnt work. I get error T.Id can not be found.

```
select 
    A.Id,
    ExistsInB = CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE EquipmentKey = A.Id) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END 
from A
```

Comment: That is a single query. Query with sub-queries is still processed as a single 'complex' query.

Comment: Are you asking us if your query works? Haven't you tried it?

Comment: Yeah. But it doesnt work. I Get T.Id column could not be found even though column exists.

Comment: You have no table named T. Just A and B.

Comment: You never specified table `T`, there's only `A`  and `B`

Comment: Your query works now that the typo `T.Id` has been fixed. However, it uses what's called a correlated sub-query. These can be inefficient, so Joe's answer is recommended.

Comment: I don't see any issue with above query.

Comment: @JaydipJ It originally had a typo referring to a non-existent table `T`. This has been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.Id, (B.EquipmentKey IS NOT NULL) AS ExistsInB
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (A.Id = B.EquipmentKey)
```

Comment: This only works when the DBMS supports Boolean and as `B.EquipmentKey` is the FK you must add `DISTINCT`